Blunder in voltage capacitor calculation
According to Ohm's Law
$$|\mathbf{V_c}|_{MAX} = |\mathbf{I_c} \mathbf{Z_c}|_{MAX} = |\mathbf{I_c} \frac{-j}{\omega C}|_{MAX} = \frac{|\mathbf{I_c}|_{MAX}}{\omega C} = \frac{I_{p}}{\omega C}$$
But now (assuming capacitor discharged at t=0):
$$ v_{c_{MAX}} = |\frac{1}{C} \int_0^{T/2} I_p \sin(\omega t) dt| = \frac{I_p}{\omega C} |\cos(\omega t)|_0^{T/2}| = \frac{2 I_p}{\omega C}$$
Explain please what is wrong here.

Thanks for your activity revising content elsewhere on the site. However, I suggest you go step by step :) Please indicate if the answer satisfies your question or modify your question accordingly to reflect your further doubts. This helps reduce the number of ghost posts and is more important than editing others' posts for clarity. Thank you.

You are missing the phase lag property which is equivalent to an initial condition in the integral. Your current dumps charge on the capacitor and then removes it. The voltage swings between a maximum and zero and never becomes negative. Your peak AC voltage swing is still given by \$\frac{I_P}{\omega C}\$, just with a DC equal to \$\frac{I_P}{\omega C}\$. In other words, for a tone at \$\omega\$:
$$V_{Peak, AC} = \frac{V_{Max} - V_{Min}}{2} = \frac{\frac{2I_P}{\omega C} - 0}{2} = \frac{I_P}{\omega C}.$$

Edit: Let us use integration to prove the point in a seemingly confusing case. Let us assume that the capacitor is initially discharged and: \$i(t) = I_P\sin(\omega t), V(0) = 0\$:
$$V(t) = V(0) + \frac{1}{C}\int_{0}^{t}I_P\sin(\omega t)\mathrm{d}t = I_P\frac{1 - \cos(\omega t)}{\omega C}.$$ Interestingly, the output still contains a DC term equal to \$ \frac{I_P}{\omega C} \$ and the peak AC voltage is the same as before:
$$V_{Peak, AC} = \frac{V_{Max} - V_{Min}}{2} = \frac{\frac{2I_P}{\omega C} - 0}{2} = \frac{I_P}{\omega C}.$$

Your answer is useful, however there is still one more doubt. Imagine a circuit with just a current source Ip.sin(wt) connected to a capacitor that starts discharged at t=0, such that my initial condition of zero voltage could be satisfied. Would my second formula be correct then? Note that the result would be different if the current source was Ip.cos(wt).

@tac I have modified my initial answer to address the confusion. In summary, the first equation always holds.

So the conclusion is that you usually use the AC formula, but be aware that a transient peak could melt ur circuit. thank you, buddy.
